# Spring boot Rest API internationlization based on request parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have a spring boot REST application with APIs having both GET and POST methods.We have few response messages that need to internationalized based on a parameter "locale" for both GET and POST.In case of GET,locale will be passed as query parameter(eg:http://sampleapp/search?locale=en) and for POST method,locale will be part of request JSON. It would be great if I could get some reference implementation for this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first I think you do not need to have locale path param. Instead of you can use the standard `Accept-Language` HTTP header property. You can read about this header [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language).

This is the way how you can read the accept-language information from the HTTP request in your rest method:

```
@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Data> getData(@RequestHeader(value="Accept-Language") String acceptLanguage)
{
    //your code goes here
}
```

Once you get the accepted language info from your client' then you can read language deppendent values from a property file with Java I18N. The following article explain you the way how to do it: https://www.google.hu/amp/s/www.journaldev.com/1370/java-i18n-internationalization-in-java/amp

Finnaly if the language info is not provided by client you can use english language as a default.

Hope that it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way of detecting user locale in web applications which can be reused in REST services is `accept-language` header. Browsers send this header with every request automatically. When it comes to detecting user locale in Spring MVC applications Spring provides us with a variety of `*LocaleResolver` classes that do the job for us. Please refer this [article](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/) for simple example.

Provided that you are using Spring REST extension to Spring MVC then it is no different here. Everything that is available for MVC can be used in `@RestController` ones. So you clients may set the `accept-language` on their requests and automatic detection will work the same way as in web application.

If you have a requirement implement a solution with locale as a POST/GET parameter then you should have a look at [`LocaleContextHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html). Spring associates a locale information with the current `Thread` and this is a way to directly access and modify it. When you set the locale using `LocaleContextHolder` later you can use it in your app components reading form the context as well as Spring standard components will be aware of another locale set.